# How to have a 2x2 figure with a 5th image centered at the bottom?

Tags: includegraphics

I would like to have 2 columns and 2 rows of images followed by one image with the same dimensions centered at the bottom of the 2x2. Here is what I have currently:

[image]

I would like to have the bottom image, "5-min.pdf" to be centered and of the same size as the other images. Here is the relevant code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1-min.pdf}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2-min.pdf}\par 
    \end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3-min.pdf}\par
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4-min.pdf}\par
\end{multicols}
\centering 
\begin{multicols}{1}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{5-min.pdf}\par 
\end{multicols}
\caption{Scatter Plots of the data sets}
\label{fig:PB2SCAT}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{1-min.pdf} &
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{2-min.pdf}\\
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{3-min.pdf} &
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{4-min.pdf}\\
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{5-min.pdf}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Scatter Plots of the data sets}
\label{fig:PB2SCAT}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Only the bottom image seems slightly smaller than the others but it could be my eyes! Thank you

Comment: You don't really need a `tabular` here. At least, I wouldn't use one. And `H` is best avoided. `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} \begin{figure}[!ht]\centering\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{1-min.pdf} 
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{2-min.pdf}\\ \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{3-min.pdf} 
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{4-min.pdf}\\ \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{5-min.pdf} \caption{Scatter Plots of the data sets} \label{fig:PB2SCAT} \end{figure} \end{document}`